# print string n times, where n= (field in first line)-1

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
X   7   1   3
X   8   1   4
X   9   1   6
X   13  2   8
X   20  6   11
Y   13  2   8
Y   19  6   10
Y   20  6   11
```

basically if we call column 2 of the first line 'n', I want to add a string to the top n-1 times so that the output is:

```
X   1   0   0
X   2   0   0
X   3   0   0
X   4   0   0
X   5   0   0
X   6   0   0
X   7   1   3
X   8   1   4
X   9   1   6
X   13  2   8
X   20  6   11
Y   13  2   8
Y   19  6   10
Y   20  6   11
```

Note that column 1 line 1 is variable. Is there a way to do this in awk?

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<$2;i++) print $1, i, 0, 0} 1' file | column -t

X  1   0  0
X  2   0  0
X  3   0  0
X  4   0  0
X  5   0  0
X  6   0  0
X  7   1  3
X  8   1  4
X  9   1  6
X  13  2  8
X  20  6  11
Y  13  2  8
Y  19  6  10
Y  20  6  11
```

Comment: In every possible way because I didn't give any code. Just a note, I think this would be faster on large files by doing the tab separation on the fly with `awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<$2;i++) print $1 "\t" i "\t" 0 "\t" 0} 1' file` I think I follow everything except the `1'` could you explain please?

Comment: `1` is for print. If your fields are of varying length tab alignment may not work  visually.  You can set `-v OFS="\t"` to set the output field separator.